# create albums photos using php mysql jquery and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, image, jquery

i have a social media website under construction and i want to build a page where users can store their uploaded image within an album like on the facebook where their are many albums that contain multiple image in it .

i did a long search about image and albums but all the tutorials was about sliding image and this cool features of jquery and ajax but and i did not get any tutorial or help about putting or categorize images within an album.

so my question if anyone can help me to learn how to create these albums , and if the is any website or video that can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen these tutorials from phpacademy? There is one about **creating albums** on an Image Upload Website (2 videos) and several on creating the image upload website.

http://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy/search?query=photo%20gallery